# How to check if an R environment exists

Tags: r

I would like to check if an R environment exists, but the standard exists() function doesn't accept an environment as argument:

```
storage <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())

storage
#<environment: 0xeb3195c>

exists(storage)
#Error in exists(storage) : invalid first argument
```

Is there any way of checking if an environment has been defined? Or is it an intrinsically wrong thing to do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`exists` takes a character argument:

```
exists("storage")
```

Though note that this will return `TRUE` even if `storage` is not an environment. You will either have to check it using `is.environment` as Señor O suggests, or pass `mode="environment"`:

```
exists("storage", mode="environment")
```

Comment: Oops, that was embarrassing. Thanks in any case, when I got the error I wrongly assumed that is was because exists() wasn't working with environments.

Comment: Reading the Usage section of a function's help page is the first thing I do when I see an error. Careful attention to the words describing the first argument often contains the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Unless I'm missing something, I think simply:

```
is.environment(storage)
```

Will do the same thing. Returns `TRUE` if it's an environment and `FALSE` if it's not (even if the object exists but is of another class).

Answer (score 0):

Is it just me or this second solution does not work?

```
is.evironment()
```

in my hands produces TRUE if you use a valid environment as argument. As soon as you try to insert a non-environment, it tries to look up in the current one for a variable with this name and returns something like

```
> is.environment(a)
  Error: object 'a' not found
```

...and of course quoting doesn't work either, because in this case it will always be a string (therefore, no error but always FALSE, also if you quote the name of an existing environment). `exists("x", mode = "environment")` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is also

```
rlang::is_environment(storage)
```

where storage is the environment name without quoting.

```r
storage <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
> storage <environment: 0x55cf33d3f288>
rlang::is_environment(storage) 
> [1] TRUE
rlang::is_environment("storage") 
> [1] FALSE
```